# get method/Function giving me an unexpected number in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have 3 files main.cpp, Student.cpp and Student.h The code is below:

**main.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;



int main()
{
    Student obj;
    obj.setName("My name is Uzair Khan. \n");
    cout << obj.getName();



    obj.setRollNumber(201);
    cout << obj.getRollNumber();

}
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include "Student.h"

void Student::setName(string x)
{
    name = x;
}

string Student::getName()
{
    return name;
}

int Student::setRollNumber(int rollNumber)
{
    int RollNum = rollNumber;
    return RollNum;
}

int Student::getRollNumber()
{
    return rollNumber;
}
```

**Student.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;



class Student
{
public:
    void setName(string x);
    string getName();
    int setRollNumber(int rollNumber);
    int getRollNumber();

private:
    string name;
    int rollNumber;
};
```

The output is very unexpected. I don't know why I am not able to get the roll number as clear integers, instead of getting Roll Number 201. I got something like this -858993460. I don't know why. I am new to C++. If anyone could help/explain, that would we very helpful.
Thank You

(Note:- I am using Visual Studio 2019 community edition)

**Output:**

```
My name is Uzair Khan.
-858993460
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyvKk.png)

Comment: `setRollNumber` never sets the `rollNumber` member.

Comment: You got `setName` right, but then you decided to declare a local variable in `setRollNumber`...

Comment: Here: `int RollNum = rollNumber;` you're doing something else that you think you're doing.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is in `Student::setRollNumber`, where you have

```
int RollNum = rollNumber;
```

What you are doing here is declaring a new local variable; what you want to do is assign to the member variable `rollNumber`. You should change the parameter name to something else, and do this:

```
int Student::setRollNumber(int n)
{
    rollNumber = n;
    return rollNumber;
}
```

Comment: Thank You Sir...Problem solved.... Thank you again Much Appreciated !!!!!!

Comment: Alternatively you can use `this->rollNumber = rollNumber;`